# How to use git status to check a directory

Tags: git, git-status

When I type 'git status'
the output is

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       var/cache/
#       var/locks/
#       var/session/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

then I try to use

```
git status var/cache/
```

and it return

```
error: pathspec 'var/cache/' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So how could I can check the status at the cache folder and locks folder

Thanks for any advice.

Yuan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kevin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582/kevin-ballard) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9678542/520162) is absolutely right: In order to be able to track changes in files, you have to tell git that you want to track changes at all.

1. add the directories to the index:
   `git add var/cache/`
   `git add var/locks/`
   `git add var/session/`
2. commit their current state:
   `git commit -m "initial"`
3. **NOW** you are able to ask git for
   `git status var/cache`
   and git will tell you what has changed.

Answer (score 5):

What status? `var/cache` is *untracked*, as in, it's not in git. It's in the filesystem, but it's not in git and it's not in the gitignore. That's why it says untracked.